# How to check OS of user then include libraries accordingly

Tags: windows, excel, macos, vba

I am currently trying to create a simple bit of VBA code that includes a specific API library if and only if the user is running Windows and not Mac.

The reason is because if the user is running Mac the code does not work since I am using a Windows API library.

What I need to do is check if the user is running Mac and SKIP including the library, else if the user is running Windows it includes the file.

Here is the code I have so far in VBA:
http://pastebin.com/fhuiumwk

```
'check if the OS is Windows
#If Not Mac Then
'get the correct API for Windows
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Get_User_Name Lib "advapi32.dll" _
  Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize _
  As Long) As Long

'function declaration for getting the Window user (dependent on the above API)
Function ExtractWindowsUser() As String
    'variables
   Dim stringBuffer As String * 100
    Dim longBufferLength As Long

    'set variables
   longBufferLength = 100
    Get_User_Name stringBuffer, longBufferLength

    'get the user's name
   ExtractWindowsUser = Left(stringBuffer, longBufferLength - 1)
End Function

'end OS check
#End If

'pre-built "function" that analyzes changes in cells
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'check OS (because I don't want to do anything if the user is running Mac)
   If Not Mac Then

        'utilizes active sheet being looked at
       With ActiveSheet

            'monitors the D column for a change
           If Not Application.Intersect(Target, .Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then

                'inserts custom function (defined above) into the desired column of current row
               .Cells(Target.Row, 4) = ExtractWindowsUser()

                'inserts NOW function to desired column of current row
               .Cells(Target.Row, 3) = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")

            'end if for intersection
           End If

        'end sheet
       End With

    'end OS check
   End If

    'If not windows do nothing

'end sub for checking change
End Sub
```

To clarify - this code runs on Windows in Excel just fine. But as soon as I try to access it from a Mac it obviously can't include the API and crashes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at conditional compilation: http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Conditional_Compilation#Built_In_Compiler_Constants

Comment: Even with changing "#If Not Mac Then" to "#If Win64 or Win32" it still registers the API on Mac

Comment: In Worksheet_change, `If Not Mac Then` needs to be `#If Not Mac Then`

Comment: @TimWilliams are you sure? Because according to your post you sent "While the #If construct is similar to the If construct, there is at least one significant difference: the #If logic has no equivalent to Not." so wouldn't "#If Not" not work at all?

Comment: That's easy enough to test - the wording in that link seems to be a bit misleading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `#` from your `If Not Mac` check:

```
'check OS (because I don't want to do anything if the user is running Mac)
#If Not Mac Then

    'utilizes active sheet being looked at
   With ActiveSheet

        'monitors the D column for a change
       If Not Application.Intersect(Target, .Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then

            'inserts custom function (defined above) into the desired column of current row
           .Cells(Target.Row, 4) = ExtractWindowsUser()

            'inserts NOW function to desired column of current row
           .Cells(Target.Row, 3) = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")

        'end if for intersection
       End If

    'end sheet
   End With

  'end OS check
 #End If
```

Re: "no use of 'Not' in conditional compilation directives" -

```
#Const NUM = False

Sub TestMe()
    #If Not NUM Then
        Debug.Print "Not NUM!"  '<<prints
    #Else
        Debug.Print "NUM!"      '<<doesn't print
    #End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So basically that little bit of information provided in that article is wrong. Because according to that code you wrote with #If Not definitely evaluates to true and prints that bit of code. Well, since I don't have access to a Mac directly right now I will have to wait and see if your method of solving the issue works. Thanks for the responses though.

Comment: I was puzzled by that also, but if you look at the last block of code on the linked page, the constants being tested are *commented out*, and there's a note about "undeclared constants"...

Comment: As soon as I am able to check this code out on a Mac I will mark your answer as correct. Should be sometime tomorrow when I can do that. Otherwise, thanks for all of the help!

Comment: Well... I tried your solution and to no avail. I honestly have no idea why it isn't working because everything I've looked at says that the #If Not Mac should make this issue resolve itself. But when I run the code via Excel on a Mac it freaks out saying "Expected Sub or Function" when it shouldn't every look for that Sub or Function because it IS a Mac and therefore should not execute the given code. Here is the up-to-date VBA code if you want to review it. But for now this question is still open. Link: http://pastebin.com/4uXMBJdE

Comment: Try using `#If Win32 Or Win64 Then` instead of `#If Not Mac`  I don't have access to a Mac so I'm unable to test.

Comment: Using #If Win32 or Win64 worked. Literally no idea why #If Not Mac doesn't work but whatever. Thank you so much for your help.